# Python fabric cant be executed from python using subproccess

Tags: python, fabric

In python I am trying to execute a fabfile and ,I get the below error from the subproccess output.  I installed fabric using easy install.  If I run the code from the command line it works.  From python no go.  I assume there is an issue with how I am using the Popen command?

```
/bin/sh: 1: fab: not found
```

Below is how I start fabric from python:

```
cmd = """fab -H 111.111.111.111 aws_bootstrap initial_chef_run:aws_server.json,aws-test,development -w """
os.chdir(fab_path) #change to the dir where the fabfile is located
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

PS  I added the below to the Popen but get the below error:

```
 executable="/bin/bash"  

/bin/bash: fab: command not found
```

From the command line I get the below which means the terminal can find fab.

```
 fab

Fatal error: Couldn't find any fabfiles!

Remember that -f can be used to specify fabfile path, and use -h for help.

Aborting.
```

Comment: Using fabrics execute command is a better option than calling a fabfile via popen.

Comment: I would try removing the `stdout` parameter - with this then the command should not execute immediately (only when you were to do something like call `p.communicate()`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the whole path for fab. To get the path to fab on your system, you can use `which fab`.

However, I can't think of any reason why calling fab from python might be better than using the [execute](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute) function of fab:

```
from fabric.tasks import execute
import my_fabfile

r = execute(my_fabfile.aws_bootstrap, hosts=["root@%s" % '111.111.111.111])
```

Return value r will contain a dict with the hosts as key(s).